# How to detect a name / last name / address / zip / CPF / CNPJ on a string?

Tags: php, string

How to detect a name / last name / address / zip / CPF / CNPJ on a string?

Eg:

In my database I have the following string :

```
  "- M-3705340 John Mark Pereira Souza CPF / CNPJ: 905438215-52 R Of TupinambÃ¡s, 275 Apt 102Bl NO NAME & nbsp; Iguaçu 35162-137 Ipatinga / MG"
```

the strings are dynamic, that is, would have to be a code that detect every piece of string, a name surname may have more than the others ...

With php, what would be the best way to separate that information?

Comment: Why you were storing it like that...

Comment: Unfortunately these are information that I have in the database. Bad information. )):

Comment: I see ur profile from brazil, am too brazilian, easier to cut make intelligent cutting position to work and uses strlen + strpos + str_replace + trim (É facil fazer isso para separar utileze strlen + strpos + str_replace + trim) .. show more 4 result, i can help and just one not good.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you find some pattern/rules that those strings follows... (e.g. Name between char 11-30). This would help to extract some string Tokens.

Afterward you could try to do some Regex tests.
Here a possible tutorial: http://regexone.com/

Comment: The strings are dynamic, I can not predict how many surnames a person has, or how many characters have the address.